# Windows 7 O.S: unable to change the Date

Tags: windows-7

I have set the date and time in Control Panel `Date and Time` Right click `Run as administrator`.

After I restarted the system.its giving the wrong date.

Example:

- Todays date is `03/19/2012`
- I changed it to `03/24/2012`
- I reboot the system.
- It displays the date as `03/19/2012`

Comment: Have u enabled automatic date/time sync with web, disable that and check again

Comment: can you please let me know ,what are steps involved to change date and time.i didnot find the sync with web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the `Clock` and click `Change time and date settings…`
Set the time under the `Date and Time` tab
And under the `Internet Time` tab, click `Change Settings`

[image]
[image]
Uncheck `Synchronize time with an Internet time server`. Then press `OK`. 
Reboot now, The time must be the one that you had set(Of course it would have advanced by a couple of sec/min based on the time taken for the system to restart).

Comment: This doesn't work for me on a Windows 2012 image running on Virtual Box. Seconds after I force the date to the future, something is restoring it back.